# How do Iindex content from the Aggregator module?

Tags: search, feeds

I use the Aggregator module to create a list of titles and snippets of articles from The Economist.

I would like to be able to search for a term like *Morality and the brain* and see the recent Economist article in the results.

Is it just a matter of change settings to use the right directory for the indexed content?

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregator module in Drupal core doesn't implement [`hook_update_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_update_index/6.x), so your options here are to either do a bit of coding in a custom module to expose the contents of the aggregated feeds to the search module, or, to use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).

I would recommend using the Feeds module, as this allows you to store imported feeds as nodes, which are then automatically included in the search index.